# How to get VIM to map dd to c-bs

Tags: vim

I've tried about 100 combinations of :inoremap and :imap, etc, but I am unable to find one that will allow me to remap  to delete the current line and leave the cursor on the line that moves up, i.e. visually, the cursor does not move.

I'd prefer to have this work in input, replace and normal modes.  Best if it covered all/most of the modes.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Including some of your best attempts and a discussion of their shortcomings might have made it easier to understand what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `set ve=all` to make sure the cursor staying on the same line, same col after deleting. Because the line below the deleted one could be shorter than the line you want to delete, E.g

```
foooooooo[I]oooo
bar
```

`[I]` is cursor, here if you press `dd`, the cursor won't go to the same column, because the `bar` line is shorter than `fooo..` line. If you `set ve=all`, your cursor could be placed to any area in the buffer.

then you can just save the col before `dd` and restore it after `dd`. like:

```
:let c=col('.') |exec 'norm! dd'.c.'|'
```

without `set ve=all`, if your cursor column didn't exceed the length of the line below, the above command works as well. but if it exceeded, the cursor would be at the end of "below" line.

I hope I understood you right.

Comment: You  answer is certainly part if not all of my answer.  However,  I have no idea how to use the `:let c=col('.') |exec 'norm! dd'.c.'|'` line.  Also, vim says `norm!` is unknown.

Comment: press `:` in your vim (Normal mode), and paste from `let c=....` to the end. `norm!` should be there, `:h norm` @WesMiller

Comment: So, how doe I get that operation to map to <C-BS>?

Comment: @WesMiller I have no idea, what `<C-BS>` does. is it `Ctrl-backspace`? what magic does it bring you?

Comment: Well, I THOUGHT it was control-backspace.

Comment: Well, I THOUGHT it was control-backspace.  Turns out that to map the key you enter `:map ` then press Ctrl-V, then Ctrl-backspace, which inserts a ^? after the `:map `.  But that isn't caret-question.  You can't type this in the vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/557082/mapping-ctrl-backspace-in-terminator) for an explanation of why I can't remap Ctrl-BackSpace.